# Moving language block in footer not getting after reference block in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, footer

I want move header language block into footer after copyright but it's display before copyright block

i have tried using

```
   <move destination="footer-container" element="store_language"  after="copyright"/>
```

but i am getting it before copyright

please see attachscreenshot

[image]

Comment: please attach screenshot

Comment: @RkRathod please check

Comment: can you try to use after="-" in your move command.